# plist localization problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, plist

I have a weird problem with my plist. I'm working with xcode 4. Whenever I try to put a localization on this plist, I can't edit it. I mean, when I edit and change a value in the plist, the application still take the old one. Even if I delete it, I still have my old plist loaded ...

I don't know if someone already got the same problem but it would help me a lot !!
Thanks

Comment: did you find the issue? Because after 3 years I encounter same problem =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simulator and the device cache the localized data. You need to remove all the data from them to see the changes, but warning! It removes all! In the device go to Settings.app -> General -> Reset -> Erase all content and settings. In the Simulator go to Simulator -> Erase all content and settings.

Comment: And so, is it possible to have a dynamic plist to display a tableView ?

Comment: For dynamic data it's better to use other type of technologies like XML, databases etc.

Comment: oups, I'm at the end of my application :)

Comment: I did that, and it's still not working. I downloaded Apple sources "internationalMountains", you can edit the plist and actually see the changes on the simulator.