# Issue with Localization in XCode 4 different result in simulator and on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have an issue with Localization in XCode 4.
I set up all in order to have my application running on both english and french.
It is working perfectly on the iPhone simulator however, on the device, localization is not working for texts comming from .strings files but it is working for .xib files.

I definitly don't get it and don't know where to look to get ride of this bug. Remember it is working on the simulator.

Does someone has an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: [Reboot the iphone][1] solved my problem (see at link for original answer)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899939/1264893

Answer (score 0):

See [plist localization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887469/plist-localization-problem)

Yann has the same problem!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Ruben. I have already checked cache issues but it's not that.
For instance, I sent the app in Ad Hoc to someone who didn't has any previous version of this app and he got the same issues.